Transient NuGet Dependencies and Versions
Using PackageReference in classic CSPROJ project files (.NET Framework 4.8).
Given the following dependency structure:
Solution (.sln)

    Project A (.csproj)

        Microsoft.Identity.Client 4.61.3 (Top-Level NuGet Reference)
            Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions (>= 6.35.0) <===

    Project B (.csproj)

        Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens 7.6.1 (Top-Level NuGet Reference)
            Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens (>= 7.6.1)
                Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging (>= 7.6.1)
                    Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions (>= 7.6.1) <===
                
        Microsoft.Identity.Client 4.61.3 (Top-Level NUGET Reference)
            Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions (>= 6.35.0) <===

The version of Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions which is present in the output directory after building, seems to differ depending on the build order:

If Project B is compiled last, it is version 7.6.1. At runtime, no error occurs, and the version numbers of all Microsoft.IdentityModel.*-Assemblies in the output directory match (7.6.1.50617).
If Project A is compiled last, it is version 6.35.0.
In this case, at runtime an error occurs, because version 6.35.0 does not satisfy the requirements of Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens 7.6.1:
"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions, Version 7.6.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of it's dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)


Is this to be expected?
What would be the best way to resolve this?

Downgrade reference to Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens in Project B to 6.35.0
Add a top-level reference to Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens 7.6.1 to Project A even though Project A does not make any usage of it?
Adding a BindingRedirect to App.config?
Better options?

